# Calling Bootstrap modal via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this javascript function:

```
function doDelete()
{
    if (root === null) {alert("Tree is Empty!"); return;}
    var strKey = document.getElementById('deleteKey').value;
    if (strKey=="") {alert("Please provide key"); return;}
    if (isNaN(strKey)) {alert("Key must be numeric"); return;}
    root = myBPT.Delete(root, strKey);
    myBPT.print_tree(root);
}
```

How can I change the alert to call a bootstrap modal instead?

This is my data-target... #printLeaves

Comment: I've tried this: $('#printLeaves').modal('show')

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is not to use JavaScript at all to show the modal but just set the appropriate  classes and data fields that allow Bootstrap to handle it. Some examples are [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals%20here). Basically, you need to wrap `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">` around your modal, then have the button look like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch modal
</button>
```

There's also an example further down if you want to trigger it with a non-button event, but then you do have to use JavaScript. I haven't done it using a separate script myself (my use case was with a button), but the documentation says you just call: `$('#myModal').modal(options)`

Comment: I'm trying to do a non-button event. I tried $('#myModal').modal(options) but it's not working.

Comment: Then replace your alerts with `$('#printLeaves').modal();` If your modal is set up correctly, it should work.

Comment: I have this function: 
function doFind()
{
 /*if (root === null) {alert("Tree is Empty!"); return;}*/
 if (root === null) {$('#printLeaves').modal(show); return;}
 var strFind = document.getElementById('findKey').value;
 if (strFind=="") {alert("Please provide key"); return;}
 if (isNaN(strFind)) {alert("Key must be numeric"); return;}
 r = myBPT.find(root, strFind);
 if (r === null)
  alert("Record not found under key " + strFind);
 else 
  alert("Record at key " + strFind + " value " + r.value);
}

I'm trying to replace the alert with the modal call. 

It's still not working.

Comment: Please use blocks to separate out code so that it is easier to read. You need quotations around `show` in the above in any case: `$('#printLeaves').modal('show')` or else `$('#printLeaves').modal({show: false})`

Comment: Nope, still not working. My JavaScript code is in a separate file and I'm just importing it in the <head> of my website.

Comment: That version doesn't attempt to use modal(), so I obviously can't see what's wrong. I suspect there's something wrong on the html side and would suggest backing up and setting up a button temporarily to get it working without JavaScript. Then you know you have the modal set up correctly and can concentrate on wiring up the JavaScript snippet.

Comment: See here for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379172/bootstrap-how-to-use-bootstrap-3-modal-for-javascript-alert/23379678?noredirect=1#comment35814706_23379678