# How to use Bootstrap 3 modal for JavaScript alert()?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

If I have an alert in my JavaScript code in the HTML header, such as:

```
<head>
...
<script>
    ...
    if (errors) {
        alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors);
    }
    ...
</script>
</head>
```

is there a way I can use a modal window from Bootstrap instead of the browser's native alert window?

If so, can someone show me a simple example for the one line of code I have above? The modal should just have an "OK" button (nothing fancy).

Comment: see:: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I saw that reference, but... I'm not sure how to integrate the javascript here.

Comment: read the doc properly, there's javascript as well not just HTML

Comment: Similar to this question (but no answers there either): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318285/calling-bootstrap-modal-via-javascript

Comment: Here's a working exammple: http://bootply.com/134106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add the html for the modal with an id

`<div id="alertModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Errors Found!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->`

Second, modify your javascript to set the content of the modal body and show it

```
<script>
...
if (errors) {
    var message = 'The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors;
    $('#alertModal').find('.modal-body p').text(message);
    $('#alertModal').modal('show')
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: Does this `<div>` tag show anything in HTML? Or, is it invisible on the page, and it's only there to support the modal window? In other words, the javascript alert() is invisible until the javascript code checks some form inputs for errors, then it appears if needed (otherwise it doesn't). When I see HTML code I automatically think something is getting drawn on the screen (that may be what's confusing me).

Comment: Div tags by default take up no space on a page, unless they have content in them. In this case, it has a class called 'modal' on it. This has a CSS rule applied to it from bootstrap.css which sets this div to 'display:none'. In other words, this div and all it's content will be hidden from view by default until the modal is shown.

Comment: Thanks so much @AbimbolaEsuruoso. Should this generally work on mobile devices (any idea)?

Comment: Will work the same on all mobile devices, as long as they have a modern browser (Firefox, IE9+, Chrome, Safari etc..)

Comment: Thanks @AbimbolaEsuruoso, this solution worked! The only issue was the `\n` in the alert text didn't produce a new line. To make it work, I changed the `<p></p>` in the `class="modal-body"` section to `<textarea></textarea>`, then changed the script `...find('modal-body p')...` to `...find('.modal.body textarea')...`.

Answer (score 4):

Ues Bootbox.js It is a small JavaScript library which allows you to create programmatic dialog boxes using Twitter’s Bootstrap modals, without having to worry about creating, managing or removing any of the required DOM elements or JS event handlers.

Here’s the simplest possible example:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
  Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
```

More details at
[Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/)